# URW Garamond installation on OS X

Tags: fonts, mactex

I'm trying to install the URW Garamond font (to be used with math design) on OS X 10.9 / MacTeX 2014. I downloaded and ran the getnonfreefonts script (without any error messages).

However when I try to compile the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
  A formula:
  \[
    \underbrace{\frac{\sin^{2}\vartheta}{\Theta_{lm}(\vartheta)}\left(\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial\vartheta^{2}}+\frac{\cos\vartheta}{\sin\vartheta}\frac{\partial}{\partial\vartheta}\right)\Theta_{lm}(\vartheta)+\sin^{2}(\vartheta)(l(l+1))}_{m^{2}}=\underbrace{-\frac{1}{\Phi_{m}(\varphi)}\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial\varphi^{2}}\Phi_{m}(\varphi)}_{m^{2}}
  \]
  and another one:
  \[
    P_l (x)\equiv\frac {1}{2^l}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor l/2\rfloor} (-1)^k \frac{(2l-2k)!}{k!(l-k)!(l-2k)!} x^{l-2k}
  \]
\end{document}
```

I still get

```
!pdfTeX error: /usr/texbin/pdflatex (file ugmr8a.pfb): cannot open Type 1 font 
file for reading
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you use `sudo getnonfreefonts-sys`? If not, do it instead of `getnonfreefonts` (requires administrator privileges).

Comment: I had the same issue some days ago. Instead of doing a system install, I refreshed the map and it worked...

Comment: @s_C Please don't suggest that. It is likely to cause you grief later on in the form of problems whose causes will not be obvious. It is *not* recommended to use the non-sys forms of the commands for font installation. (At least, it is not recommended for unix-like systems which include OS X.) Only use the non-sys commands if you really have to e.g. because you don't have administrator rights on the machine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whenever possible, the `-sys` utilities should be used; this holds for

```
 fmtutil-sys

 updmap-sys

 getnonfreefonts-sys
```

The first utility is for recreating format files, the second one for updating the map files necessary for using Type1 fonts and not the bitmap versions, the third one is the main important for the purpose of your question.

In general fonts that are not provided directly by TeX Live should be installed system wide in the `TEXMFLOCAL` tree, using `sudo updmap-sys` for updating the map files and `getnonfreefonts(-sys)` is just a special case, because it provides an automatic procedure for installing some font families.

Why is it better to use the local tree and system-wide installation? Because in this way we are guaranteed that any update to the fonts in TeX Live will be reflected in the map files. If one uses `updmap` (or `getnonfreefonts`) a set of map files are created for the *current user only*. Since `tlmgr` (or TeX Live Utility on Mac OS X) only run `updmap-sys`, changes will not be reflected in the user's `pdftex.map` file or related.

So, use

```
sudo getnonfreefonts-sys garamond garamondx
```

but first check that the command line

```
kpsewhich pdftex.map
```

outputs

```
/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map
```

If the result is different, remove the file pointed at.

Answer (score 0):

After updating TeXLive 2018 and TeXShop this worked for me.

Rico A.R. Picone, PhD wrote in [Reinstalling nonfreefonts](http://ricopic.one/2017/03/21/reinstalling-everything/)

> To get fonts like uw-garamond, run the following command or see more
>   here.

```
curl --remote-name https://tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/install-getnonfreefonts

sudo texlua install-getnonfreefonts
```

> Then update the “TeX filename database” with the following. It’s worth
>   reviewing this documentation.

```
sudo -H mktexlsr

sudo -H updmap-sys --force --enable Map=newfont.map

sudo texlua install-getnonfreefonts
```

> It I kept having an error updmap [ERROR] in which it couldn’t locate
>   newfont.map, although the file was where it said it was supposed to
>   be! I think the above sequence works, but I could be wrong.

**Updated: see picture below**[image: **Output**]