# Problem with installing mathtime pro 2 font

Tags: fonts, installing, texlive, mtpro

Okay I know there have been posted very similar questions like these. However their solutions do not seem to work in my case.

I tried to install Mathtime Pro 2. I have texlive 2013 and Ubuntu 14.04. I first did found this topic: [Help using MathTime Pro 2 fonts in Ubuntu Linux with tex-live](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87300/help-using-mathtime-pro-2-fonts-in-ubuntu-linux-with-tex-live) after which it refers to [Problems installing MathTime Professional 2 font on TexLive](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75679/problems-installing-mathtime-professional-2-font-on-texlive).

I tried their solutions but I still keep getting the error

```
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 4+0/600 --dpi 2400 mt2exf
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for mt2exf.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
 )
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file mt2exf): Font mt2exf at 2400 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

The log file from the installer provided by [Problems installing MathTime Professional 2 font on TexLive](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75679/problems-installing-mathtime-professional-2-font-on-texlive) can be found here: http://pastebin.com/Gk9AHuFP

I also tried with the lite version but that does not seem to work either.

I have to note that I recently also installed MinionPro font. During the install of that font I also stumbled onto problems.

I hope someone can help me with this problem.

--edit--

So I removed all my texlive installations and all files and folders. I downloaded the new texlive version, 2014, and installed it using the installer. I installed it with the following settings:

[image]

Now where do I need to put (merge) the `texmf` folder of mtpro2? `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local` or `/usr/local/share/texmf` or `~/.texmf`?

Afterwhich I need to run

```
sudo texhash
sudo updmap-sys --disable mt-belleek.map --nomkmap
sudo updmap-sys --disable belleek.map --nomkmap
sudo updmap-sys --disable mt-yy.map --nomkmap
sudo updmap-sys --disable mt-plus.map --nomkmap
sudo updmap-sys --enable Map mtpro2.map
```

and maybe `vim $(kpsewhich updmap.cfg)`, add `Map mtpro2.map` and run `sudo updmap-sys`. Correct?

Comment: This clearly seems a problem with the `.map` file. Did you run `updmap-sys`? Did you add the relevant entry in the `updmap.cfg` file? The message `The following map file(s) couldn't be found: mtpro2.map (in /etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg)` seems clear about the problem.

Comment: In other words, did you do `updmap-sys --enable Map mtpro2.map`?

Comment: Yes I did. I also checked `sudo vim $(kpsewhich updmap.cfg)`. And it does contain `Map mtpro2.map`. I should note however that my `updmap.cfg` is located at `/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg` when I run `kpsewhich updmap.cfg` Not at `/etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg`. Both `.cfg`-files do however contain `Map mtpro2.map`.

Comment: Do you have multiple installations of TeX Live? The output from `kpsewhich` suggests that you are using TL installed using upstream's installer while the presence of the file in `/etc` and the information in your question suggests that you are using TL from Ubuntu. It is not a good idea to have multiple installations from different distributions. (It is fine to have e.g. TL 2013 and TL 2014 from upstream but mixing TL from upstream with TL from Ubuntu will almost certainly cause problems.) When you ran `updmap-sys` which file did it use? What was the output? What is  your user's  `PATH`?

Comment: Yes that might be true that I have multiple texlive installations. I installed texlive 2013 manually. However, when I wanted to install `ipe` on Ubuntu, it also installed the base packages of texlive by default. Which I did not want, but do not know how to cancel, it is mandatory.

Comment: @cfr my `PATH` is `/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux/:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/home/wouter/.local/bin`

Comment: You need to install a dummy package to keep your package manage happy. Then you can install stuff like `ipe` without dragging in Ubuntu's `texlive` packages. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/39222 for details. (Except that you should not install as root but nobody takes any notice of that, it seems.)

Comment: @cfr I updated my question. I removed texlive (all files and folders), installed texlive 2014, installed a dummy package, downloaded the ipe .deb files and installed them. For now everything works again. How do I proceed with installing mtpro2? I updated my question.

Comment: Everything extra should be installed under `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local` and `mktexlsr` should be run. Append `Map mtpro2.map` to the file `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/web2c/updmap.cfg` (create it, if it doesn't exist) and run `updmap-sys`. All of this with administrator privileges.

Comment: @egreg, this seemed to work! Thank you very much! Can I ask is this also the default manner on installing fonts? Put them in the `TEXMFLOCAL` folder, run `mktexlsr` and append the map file to `$TEXMFLOCAL/web2c/updmap.cfg`?

Comment: @WG Yes. For fonts which (1) are packaged for TeX and (2) are not part of TeX Live, that is how to do it. Note that you can say `updmap-sys --enable Map=mtpro2.map` rather than editing `updmap.cfg`. If you are adding several maps, editing the file is easier but if it is just one or two, sometimes it is easier to use `--enable`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this answer I assume a standard TeX Live is used, not one packaged by Debian, Fedora or similar distributions.

Extra material should be installed either in `TEXMFLOCAL` or `TEXMFHOME`. The first location is

```
/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local
```

while `TEXMFHOME` refers to `~/texmf` (`~/Library/texmf` with MacTeX).

Fonts should always be installed in `TEXMFLOCAL` for several reasons (see the related question [URW Garamond installation on OS X](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186623/urw-garamond-installation-on-os-x)).

This of course requires administrator privileges.

- Install the material by expanding the archive at the top level of `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local` or by moving manually the files.
- Run `mktexlsr`.
- Open the file

  ```
  /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/web2c/updmap.cfg
  ```

  (creating it if necessary) and append the line

  ```
  Map mtpro2.map
  ```
- Run `updmap-sys`

This should make the fonts available to all users of the system.

---

**Note.** Although

```
updmap-sys --enable-map mtpro2.map
```

(with administrator privileges) instead of the last two steps above appears to work in the same way, there is a big advantage in doing as explained above: when TeX Live 2015 will be issued and installed, the file `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/web2c/updmap.cfg` will remain exactly the same and the run of `updmap-sys` made by the installation procedure will make the MathTime Pro fonts available in the new release without having to remember activating them manually.

Comment: thank you for this answer. I was planning on typing this myself, but you already did :-). I think this is also a very clear text when you want to install any font.