# Installing WebOMintsGD font in Tex Live 2015 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: fonts, texlive, ubuntu

I wonder how to correctly install the `WebOMintsGD` font in `Tex Live 2015` on `Ubuntu 14.04`. I tried the following code but without any success:

```
wget http://tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/install-getnonfreefonts
sudo texlua install-getnonfreefonts
getnonfreefonts -a
```

But when I compile some files using `WebOMintsGD`, I get the following error: `LaTeX errors: !pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file WebOMintsGD): Font WebOMintsGD at 720 not found`. I think I'm not installing fonts correctly. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

**Edited**

I upgraded `Tex Live` from `2013` to `2015` on `Ubuntu 14.04` using the guidelines given [in this nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95373/4821). But have some problems. After upgrading when I check the version of `Tex Live` using `tex --version` command it gives the the following information:

```
TeX 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.1.1
Copyright 2013 D.E. Knuth.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the TeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the TeX source.
Primary author of TeX: D.E. Knuth.
```

Then I edited `~/.profile` and added 
`PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/i386-linux/:$PATH` at the end of the file `.profile`.

Then also: `MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/doc/man:$MANPATH` and `INFOPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/doc/info:$INFOPATH`.

I also used `sudo getnonfreefonts-sys -a` to install the packages and it say

```
Package 'webomints' already installed and no update available.
```

But even after this I'm still getting the same error.

**Edited**

Firstly I removed `/.texlive2015` using

```
rm -rfv ~/.texlive2015
```

and installed fonts using

```
getnonfreefonts-sys -a
```

The command

```
getnonfreefonts -l
```

says

```
Installation directory: /home/yaseen/texmf
------------------------------------------
arial-urw      Arial (URW)                                          [installed]
classico       Classico (URW & Bob Tennent)                         [installed]
dayroman       DayRoman (Apostrophiclabs)                           [installed]
eurofont       Euro symbols (Adobe)                                 [installed]
garamond       GaramondNo8 (URW)                                    [installed]
garamondx      GaramondNo8 Expert (Michael Sharpe)                  [installed]
lettergothic   LetterGothic (URW)                                   [installed]
luximono       LuxiMono (Bigelow & Holmes)                          [installed]
vntex-nonfree  VnTeX nonfree (Han The Thanh)                        [installed]
webomints      Webomints (Galapagos Design Group)                   [installe
```

But `~/texmf$ ls` doesn't show these font files.

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "without any success"? Did the installation failed?

Comment: When I compile some files using `WebOMintsGD`, I get the following error: `LaTeX errors: !pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file WebOMintsGD): Font WebOMintsGD at 720 not found`.

Comment: It would be helpful if you look through your file structure, and see whether or not files are where you expect them to be. Then, we will know whether the installation completely failed, or whether the problem is with to connection to Latx.

Comment: How did you install TeX Live? If you installed from upstream, try removing `~/.texlive2015` and running `sudo getnonfreefonts-sys -a`. *Never* use `getnonfreefonts` unless you have no other choice.

Comment: @cfr: How I can remove `~/.texlive2015`?

Comment: @MYaseen208 It is just a directory. You can rename or remove it. (Only remove it if you are 100% positive it is the right one.) How did you install TL?

Comment: @cfr I'm curious, why not installing `getnonfreefonts`?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina It is OK to install it. Just don't use it. Once you install the fonts with that command, you must remember to run `updmap` every time you update your TeX distribution using TeX Live Manager. If you don't, weird things could happen, you won't get new fonts installed, you won't get updates for font packages you use etc. If you don't have permission to run `getnonfreefonts-sys`, `getnonfreefonts` is your only choice. Though it is worth asking how badly you need the extra fonts in that case. Otherwise, there is simply no reason to use it.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina The same thing happens if you run `updmap` directly, of course. You either have to undo the effects or remember to run it every time you update the installation. And then weird things happen eventually.

Comment: @cfr I see. Are those problems with `getnonfreefonts` documented? This is the firts time I hear about those inconvenients.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I don't know. It comes up a reasonable amount in comments. I'm not sure that counts as its being documented exactly.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina [egreg](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186623/urw-garamond-installation-on-os-x/186628#186628) [me](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251851/problem-with-loading-mathb-font-metrics-file-in-linux/251940#251940), [me](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155243/font-doesnt-load-without-using-pdfmapfile-command-why/156064#156064), [egreg](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41254/xetex-complains-about-missing-kanjix-map/41279#41279), ...

Comment: [egreg](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47662/do-i-need-to-run-non-tlmgr-tools-each-time-i-use-tex-live-utility-to-update-tex/47667#47667), ... many more. (Some are even not by egreg.)

Comment: @cfr Ah, thanks. I never saw those, case I usually don't read question about fonts.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina There are more answers on it than I realised. I didn't even remember writing any which is why I said it comes up a lot in comments ;).

Comment: @cfr: Please see edits and guide me accordingly. Thanks

Comment: @RobtA: Please see my edits and guide me accordingly. Thanks

Comment: @MYaseen208, what does `which pdflatex` say? is the `texmf-local/` shared by the 2013 and 2015 installations? In which case the fonts does not need to be installed again, but you need to activate all the `.map` files in `texmf-local`

Comment: @daleif:  `which pdflatex` says `/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/i386-linux//pdflatex`.

Comment: @MYaseen208, so that is fine. Go to `/usr/local/texlive/` and see if `texmf-local` is there, if it is then it is shared, and webomints are presumably already in `texmf-local/fonts/type1/public`, thus you will need to activate the appropriate `.map` files.

Comment: @MYaseen208, the files are presumably not added to `~/texmf`, I do not even have that folder.

Comment: @daleif: I do have `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/type1` but no `/public` folder.

Comment: Did you run `getnonfreefonts-sys` as root? I assume TL15 is installed by root given that it is located in `/usr/local/`. Since I'm the only user on this system, I typically install in `/opt/texlive` where I own that folder. In that case `getnonfreefonts-sys` automatically installed into `/opt/texlive/texmf-local` in my case. No mentioning of `~daleif/texmf/`

Comment: @daleif: No I did not run `getnonfreefonts-sys` neither `TL15` as root.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25908/discussion-between-myaseen208-and-daleif).

Comment: @MYaseen208: Got your request for more help, but I see that the others have already provided help above my level of expertise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is most likely because the `getnonfreefonts` are already available in the shared `texmf-local/` folder in `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local`. However the corresponding `Map` files are not enabled and thiws LaTeX does not know where the fonts are. Thus these `.map` files have to be enabled.

Ulrike Fischer mentioned that since these fonts are not related to `tlmgr` it might be an idea to make a custom `updmap.cfg` for `texmf-local` which `updmap` will then pick up and use.

Here is how I made mine (you might need to be root)

1. Go to `texmf-local`, on my setup this is `/opt/texlive/texmf-local`, you can ask TL you provide it via `kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFLOCAL`
2. Make sure the `web2c` subfolder exists, make it if it does not exist
3. Now run

   ```
   find . -name \*.map
   ```

   Which will find all the `.map` files under `texmf-local`.
4. Copy this output into `web2e/updmap.cfg` and edit it so each line looks like

   ```
   Map name.map
   ```

   (you will need to remove a lot of `./path/path/` stuff)
5. Now run

   ```
   texhash
   updmap-sys --syncwithtrees
   ```

   The first command updates the ls-R DBs, so LaTeX now knows about our extra `updmap.cfg`. The other command use this extra information to sync all the `updmap` information.

You can test that it works with

```
 updmap-sys --listmaps | grep webo
```

As `webo.map` is the Map file for WeboMints

For reference, here is what my `/opt/texlive/texmf-loca/web2c/updmap.cfg` ended as:

```
Map dayroman.map
Map webo.map
Map ugm.map
Map zgm.map
Map ffu.map
Map ua1.map
Map ulg.map
Map zpeu.map
Map classicovn.map
Map garamondvn.map
Map ul9.map
Map classico.map
```

(duplicates removed)

Comment: after a year I have the same problem when I upgraded Texlive. Now the output of `which pdflatex` is `/usr/bin/pdflatex`. Would appreciate if you help me to figure out the same problem again with `Texlive 2016`. Waiting for your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Exactly what did you install? If you compare the pdflatex location with the one from your original question, they are very different.

Answer (score 1):

I like to share a successed instalation of WebOMints on TeXlive 2019 on Ubuntu 20.04.

On terminal:

```
wget http://tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/install-getnonfreefonts
sudo texlua install-getnonfreefonts
sudo getnonfreefonts --sys -a
```

With this, the following fonts were successfully installed system-wide (I tested WebOMints):
`arial-urw`, `classico`, `dayroman`, `gandhi`, `garamond`, `garamondx`, `lettergothic`, `literaturnaya`, `luximono`, `vntex-nonfree`, `webomints`.

For non system-wide installations, see [TeX Live updmap and fmtutil, -sys vs. -user](https://tug.org/texlive/scripts-sys-user.html)